# How to make space between icon and label in Charts iOS Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, charts, insets

I using Chart component for iOS Swift.
My chart contains icon and label(digit number). 
And my number label is behind of icon.
How to fix this problem.
I can move my icon like this:

```
iconsOffset
```

But I wanna move label top of icon.

Comment: Which charts are you using ?

Comment: @dip https://github.com/danielgindi/Charts